# Reshape long to wide table in SQL

Tags: sql, reshape, collapsable

I have a dataset with variables ID, Vaccine, and Date.
Some Vaccines have a single date, and some vaccines have two or three dates for a single ID. When I create a table in SQL, multiple rows are created for the
IDs that have two or more dates for a vaccine. See an example below:

| ID | Vaccine | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Flu | 1/15/2005 |
| A | Flu | 3/25/2005 |
| B | Flu | 1/15/2005 |
| B | TB | 1/15/2005 |
| B | TB | 2/15/2005 |
| B | TB | 3/15/2005 |
| B | Flu | 4/18/2005 |
| C | Flu | 1/15/2005 |
| C | TB | 5/21/2005 |

How can I create a table as below in SQL?

| ID | Vaccine | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Flu | 1/15/2005 | 3/25/2005 |  |
| B | Flu | 1/15/2005 | 4/18/2005 |  |
| B | TB | 1/15/2005 | 2/15/2005 | 3/15/2005 |
| C | Flu | 1/15/2005 |  |  |
| C | TB | 5/21/2005 |  |  |

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried any SQL code that doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you want to create that? You have data and read it with your code and process and display it as you want.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The answer might use product specific features.

Comment: What's expected to happen when A has a 4:th dose? Ignore, switch out 1:st date, or add an additional column?

Comment: Thank you all for providing the solution and comments. Both solutions are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    Vaccine,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Date END) AS Date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Date END) AS Date2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Date END) AS Date3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        Vaccine,
        Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Vaccine ORDER BY Date) AS rn
    FROM 
        YourTableName
) AS subquery
GROUP BY 
    ID, Vaccine;
```

In this query:

1. The inner subquery assigns a row number (rn) to each row within the
   same ID and Vaccine partition, ordered by the Date.
2. The outer query
   uses CASE expressions to pivot the dates based on their row number
   (rn). The MAX() function is used to aggregate the dates for each ID
   and Vaccine combination.

Make sure to replace **YourTableName** with the actual name of your table. This query will transform the data into the format you desire, with Date1, Date2, and Date3 columns indicating the different dates for each ID and Vaccine combination.

Answer (score 1):

To reshape a long tb to a wide tb you can use a combination of conditional aggregation.

**Example**

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Vaccine,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Date END) AS Date1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Date END) AS Date2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Date END) AS Date3
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        Vaccine,
        Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Vaccine ORDER BY Date) AS rn
    FROM TBName
) AS Ranked
GROUP BY ID, Vaccine, rn
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Date END) IS NOT NULL;
```